# chat application in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I want create chat for automation website, so client not send any request to server for respond, instead server send respond to client when received a message from other client

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/):

> Async library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive
>   web applications.

[SignalR: example chat application](http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/12/14/signalr-starter-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Vijay u need to implement Reverse ajax type of thing .
Check out comet and other ways to do it . 
Check it out [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax1/index.html)